# Append incrementing values to DB column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Current Status

```
column1 = 'post_type=coupons&#038;p='
column2 = 'post_type=coupons&#038;p='
column3 = 'post_type=coupons&#038;p='
```

Some Query

```
UPDATE wp_posts set `guid`='post_type=coupons&#038;p=' + keepIncreasingNum;
```

Desired result

```
column1 = 'post_type=coupons&#038;p=11'    
column2 = 'post_type=coupons&#038;p=12'
column3 = 'post_type=coupons&#038;p=13'
```

Please help me with the query.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  MySQL does not recognize `+` in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with variables:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
    set `guid` = concat('post_type = concat(coupons&#038;p=', (@var := coalesce(@var, 0) + 1));
```

You might want an `order by`, if you want the numbers assigned in a particular order.

Comment: is 0 the start value ?

Comment: @KaNcH . . . No, 1 would be.

Comment: all column was set 1 .. Its was completely wrong. Ruined by DB